# gtkmm-Window remains empty

Tags: gtk, window, gtkmm

In our project, we're using `gtkmm` and we have several classes that extend `Gtk::Window` in order to display our graphical interface.

I now found out what call produces the behaviour (described in the previous revision. The question now slightly changed.)

We're displaying one window, works like a charm.

Then, we have a window which displays various status messages. Let's call it `MessageWindow`. It has a method `setMessage(Glib::ustring msg)` which simply calls a label's `set_text()`.

After some processing, we hide this window again and we now show a toolbar. Just yet another simple window, nothing crazy.

For all windows applies: The main thread calls `show()` on the window and creates a new thread which calls `Gtk::Main::run()` (without argument).

That's how it should be, until now.

The problem starts here: The main thread now wants to call `MessageWindow::setMessage("any string")`. a) if I call this method, the message window reacts completely correctly. **But** afterwards, the toolbar-window is displayed empty. b) if I don't call it, the message window doesn't change the label (which is absolutely clear), and the toolbar window is displayed as it should.

Seems like the windows are messing up each other.

Now the question:

**If my gui-thread is blocking in `Gtk::Main::run()`, how can I now change the text of a label?**

We're using `gtkmm-2.4` (and no, we cannot upgrade)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow! That's complicated...

First: you should not manipulate windows from several threads. That is you should have just one GUI thread that does all the GUI work, and let the other threads communicate with it.

It is theoretically possible to make it work (in Linux; in Windows it is impossible) but it is more trouble than it is worth.

Second: the line `Gtk::Main main(argc, argv)` is not a call, it is an object declaration. The object main should live for the duration of the program, so if you use it in a object constructor, as soon as you return from it, the object will be destroyed! Just put it at the top of the main function and forget about it.

**UPDATE**: My usual approach here is to create a pipe, a g_io_channel to read, and write bytes on the other end.

Other option, although I didn't test it is to call get the `GMainContext` of the main thread and then `g_idle_source_new()` and attach that source to the main context with  `g_source_attach()`. If you try this one and it works, please post your result here!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I knew about the lifetime of `Gtk::Main`. This thing lives as long as the controller does. Generally, I only access the GUI from the same thread. But there's one exception, which seems to be causing the problem. I'm modifying my question

Comment: But note the thread that creates the Gtk::Main should be the one&only that creates windows and manipulates them. Your question seems to imply that you call `show` in one thread and call `run` in other.

Comment: yes. that's what I'm doing. seemed to work without any problems... how could it be solved otherwise? running all the actions right from the gui?

Comment: okay. I now changed this. But how to update the GUI with GTK while something is running in the background? We have callbacks in this background-process and need to post status messages in the gui from these callbacks. In Java, there's something like `invokeLater()`.

Comment: No problem running other threads, just do not access to the windows from them. Use the "idle" the "pipe" tricks that I describe in the updated reply to queue actions to be ran in the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for the good point. I solved it differently - and as intended by the gtkmm-developers. I first push the string to set as message to a SafeQueue<string> (my wrapper around std::queue implementing thread-safety) and then used a Glib::Dispatcher to send a notification that there's something new in it. Works like a charm

Comment: @Atmocreations Cool! Glib::Dispatcher is actually a nice Gtkmm wrapper around a pipe and a g_io_channel, I think.

Comment: yes. although i think it's a bit bad you cannot pass any parameters that way. I just put it into a mutually excluding container and that's enough for what I'm doing.